# ImportError: cannot import name 'errorcode' from 'mysql.connector'

Tags: python, flask, mysql-connector

Error module seems to be missing from mysql.connector.

I am using Python 3.10.11 and Flask 2.3.2 to make an API for a MySQL database. More specifically I am having trouble with the error package. When I try to run the Flask app, I get the error below.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'errorcode' from 'mysql.connector'
```

I can confirm the MySQL database is available for connection, as I have been able to connect to it through other methods.
Here is my python code.

```
import mysql.connector, requests, os
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import json
from flask import (Flask, redirect, render_template, request,send_from_directory, url_for)

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route("/connect")
@cross_origin()
def connect():
    host=os.environ.get("MYSQL_HOST")
    try:
        db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=os.environ.get("MYSQL_HOST"),
            user=os.environ.get("MYSQL_USER"),
            database=os.environ.get("MYSQL_NAME"),
            password=os.environ.get("MYSQL_PASSWORD"),
            port=3306
        )

        if db.is_connected:
            return "Connected to " + host
        else: 
            return "Failed to connect to " + host
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        return "Something went wrong: {}".format(err)
```

I have also tried importing like this:

```
from mysql.connector.errors import Error
```

My virtual environment is using mysql-connector-python 8.1.0, which I believe is the latest. As I expand the API to use more complex endpoints in the future, I would really like to be able to use the Exceptions defined in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors.html)

Does anyone have any ideas why the Error module seems to be missing from the mysql-connector-python package?

The app will build and run without importing error or errorcode but I would like to be able to use them. I have installed the latest version of the connector.

Comment: Perhaps you should `print(mysql.connector.__file__)` and see if it looks like you are using the official version.  Maybe you have a name conflict somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a REPL session.

Type `import mysql`.

Now do `dir(mysql)`

you should see `connector` as one of the submodules.

Now do `dir(mysql.connector)` and see what is available.

I'm guessing that the correct import should be
`from mysql.connector import Error`

Comment: I followed the steps you listed but just on my own machine, and I was able to verify the errors and errorcode files are indeed installed in the mysql connector. The issue seems to have resolved after I restarted my computer. Appreciate the response!